# How do we write query with IN() in zend framework?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

I have the below sql query:

> SELECT * FROM `tbl_location_manager` WHERE locid IN (4,5) AND
>   lctype!=3

I have written query with where = condition as

```
$sqlSelect = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
$sqlSelect->where(array('locid' => '4'));
```

but not found any solution for IN().

Comment: Try where('status_id IN(?)', $data);

Comment: This is giving me sql error. My query is:
$sqlSelect = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
            $sqlSelect->where('lcid IN (?)',array(2,3));
But it prints with empty parameter as:
SELECT `tbl_location_manager`.* FROM `tbl_location_manager` WHERE lcid IN ();

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution :

```
use Zend\Db\Select\Where;

$where = new Where();
$where->in('locid', [4, 5]);
$sqlSelect = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
$sqlSelect->where($where);
```

Comment: Got the Solution.

$sqlSelect = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

$sqlSelect->where->in('locid',[4, 5]);
$statement = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->prepareStatementForSqlObject($sqlSelect);
            $resultSet = $statement->execute();

Thanks everyone for help.